# ¿Como hacer que un proceso padre espere al proceso hijo para terminar su ejecución en C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo este código

```
int main(){
 pid_t child = fork();
 if (child == 0) {
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    sleep(10);
 }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que el programa principal espere los 10 segundos del sleep() para acabar el programa, pero no se como hacer que el proceso hijo "child" le comunique al padre que aun no ha acabado

Comment: Con el fork creas un proceso hijo y uno padre, pero solo controlas el hijo, por lo que en realidad el fork no te ha servido de nada, puede ser?

Comment: Creo que seria bueno que investigaras sobre `waitpid`.

Comment: @awacate creo que la funcion usa milisegundos ,pusiste 10 milisegundos en en codigo,si quieres 10 segundos pon 10.000

Comment: @awacate creo que la funcion sleep(); comienza con S mayuscula

Answer (score 0):

Para esperar que un hilo acabe, tienes que hacer `join`.

---

Usa los hilos estándar de C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void f()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(15));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Lanzando tarea\n";
    std::thread tarea(f);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << "Han pasado 10 segundos, esperamos a la tarea\n";
    tarea.join();
    std::cout << "La tarea ha acabado\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[[Wandbox]三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kzZ4RakOQsi6qiIG)</kbd>